Slightly confused about relationship between SQL tables and predicate logic
I think of an "ontology" of SQL as follows (which may be incorrect or incomplete):

tables
table names
columns
column names
data types
data type names
data type values
records (/rows)

A minimal example would be a table $T$, with name "TableName", and a column $a$ with name "ColumnName" and data type $d$ with name "DataTypeName", generated by this query:
create table TableName ( ColumnName DataTypeName ) ;

We can add a record $r$ to this table by specifying the data type values (of correct data type) for each column of that table. In this case, the only column is $a$, so we can add datum $v$ of data type $d$. This query does that:
insert into TableName ( ColumnName ) value ;

I think SQL is based on relational algebra, and I think of "relations" as predicates, of the form $R(x),\; S(x, y),\; T(x, y, z), \ldots$, so this makes me think of predicate (first-order) logic. I am trying to work out how precisely they correspond to one another.
If we have a table Man with attributes name, age, and favorite_color, and I create a record in Man with values Steve, 23, brown, I think we have a constant $c$ in a signature $\Sigma$, with formulae $$name(c) = Steve,\; age(c) = 23,\; favorite\_color(c) = brown$$. Perhaps we can either imagine $Steve$ is an element (a name) in a set of names, $23$ is an element (an age) in a set of ages, and $brown$ (a color) is an element in a set of colors; or, in a computational implementation, that $Steve$ is the string "Steve", $23$ the integer 23, and $brown$ the string "brown".
I suppose this makes me wonder where, if at all, the idea of the table, "Man", gets reflected, in logic. For example, is it actually a conjunctive formula, $$man(x) := name(x) \wedge age(x) \wedge favorite\_color(x)$$? I don't know if this is conceptually accurate. In logic, I think we would say, $$man(x) \leftrightarrow name(x) \wedge age(x) \wedge favorite\_color(x)$$; and this is a logical assertion that "if someone is a man, then they have a name, an age, and a favorite color; and vice versa". However, it does not feel like an SQL table is such a strict assertion. First of all, records can leave certain columns blank. Second of all, the SQL table Man is not intended to assert "what a man is", but only to enable possible features of a given man; and it's not intended to be an exhaustive list of features either. Contrary to the logical formula above, we would be more inclined to say, "If someone is a man, they may have a name, an age, and/or a favorite color; if something has any of those things, though, it is not necessarily a man."
So how do we resolve this mismatch, and basically translate SQL tables into logical theories, if possible?
